Best Practices for Azure Alert Management Across Multiple Subscriptions with action groups
I am currently managing around 100 different Azure subscriptions and I want to allow subscription owners to create their own alerts. However, I want all these alerts to use the same Logic App to send the alerts via an Action Group.
At the moment, I have a centralized Action Group, but I am unsure about the best practices in this scenario. Should I grant all subscription owners permissions to my centralized Action Group, or should I create an individual Action Group per subscription that uses the Logic App?
If the centralized solution is the recommended approach, what permissions are needed for the owners to be able to see and use the Action Group for their alerts?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
If it is the centrialized solution, what permissions is needed for the owners to be able to see and use the action group for their alerts?

To grant subscription owners permissions to the centralized Action Group, they need to be added as members to the Action Group and given the appropriate permissions. The recommended permissions are "Reader" or "Contributor" role for the subscription owners.

To allow subscription owners to create their own alerts that use the same Logic App to send the alerts via an Action Group, it is recommended to create a centralized Action Group. Subscription owners can then be granted permissions to use the centralized Action Group for their alerts. This approach ensures consistency and simplifies management.
